# How to check sent text in OnActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I need to be able to check if the user has sent the text I set in my code;

```
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text I want to send");
```

or has changed the prefixed text (on the SMS client app, email client app, or the app that gets launched by the intent) before sending it.

I need to know this because sharing my game link will give a reward to the user, so I need to check if that link is correctly shared.

I would appreciate any answer that could help.

Thanks.

Comment: did you send it with sendBroadcast ?

Comment: No, just startActivityForResult(messageIntent); Is there any way to do so by using sendBroadcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACTION_SEND` isn't documented to return a result. So starting the intent with `startActivityForResult()` will return the default result: `RESULT_CANCELED`. That is, unless the receiving app has implemented support for returning a result; which is highly unlikely because it's not part of the documented behavior.

In summary, what you want to do is not possible with any of the common Intents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
String message = "Your Message";
intent.putExtra("IDENTIFIER", message);
```

And where you are going to receive the message...

```
String messageReceived = getIntent().getExtras().get("IDENTIFIER").toString();
```

Comment: I think that would not retrieve the text that the user have actually sent, but the default text I have set as an extra. Thanks anyway!